# Nipype SPM12 / Matlab Compiler Runtime interface functions

Tags: python, matlab-spm, nipype

I'm trying to run SPM functions via Nipype but i get the same error when calling different SPM functions.

I can successfully connect to the Matlab compiler runtime and execute commands via nipype like so:

```
import nipype.interfaces.matlab as matlab
mlab = matlab.MatlabCommand()
mlab.inputs.script = 'spm ver'
mlab.run()
```

I can also import spm from nipype interfaces:

```
from nipype.interfaces import spm
matlab_cmd = "opt/MATLAB Runtime/v99/toolbox/spm12_r7771/spm12/run_spm12.sh opt/MATLAB/MATLAB Runtime/v99 script"
spm.SPMCommand.set_mlab_paths(matlab_cmd=matlab_cmd, use_mcr=True)
```

However, when i run the following (or other spm functions), e.g.

```
spm.SPMCommand().version
```

I end up with the same error, see:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 File C:\Anaconda\envs\ConcSpace\lib\site-packages\nipype\utils\spm_docs.py:49, in 
_strip_header(doc)
 48 try:
---> 49     index = doc.index(hdr)
 50 except ValueError as e:

ValueError: substring not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

[full error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H23o.png)

I'm not sure its because of missmatching versions of MCR or wrong paths i set?
I have Matlab2020b as well as the MCR installed separately on a win10 machine.
Nipype is up to date and running on a conda env in jupyterlab.

Glad for any tips that could fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: did you solve it? I have this problem too :(